# How to fill NaN with user defined value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to fill NaN with user defined value in pandas dataframe.

For text columns like A and B, user defined text like 'Missing' should be imputed. For discrete numeric variables like C and D, median value should be imputed. I have many columns like these, I would like apply rule for all vars in the dataframe

DF

```
 A           B            C          D
A0A1       Railway        10         NaN
A1A1       Shipping       NaN        1
NaN        Shipping       3          2
B1A1       NaN            1          7
```

DF out:

```
 A           B            C          D
A0A1       Railway        10         2
A1A1       Shipping       3          1
Missing    Shipping       3          2
B1A1       Missing        1          7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fun way!**

```
d = {np.dtype('O'): 'Missing'}
df.fillna(df.dtypes.map(d).fillna(df.median()))

         A         B     C    D
0     A0A1   Railway  10.0  2.0
1     A1A1  Shipping   3.0  1.0
2  Missing  Shipping   3.0  2.0
3     B1A1   Missing   1.0  7.0
```

Comment: What do you think about my solution?

Comment: Lol,  just posted that.  Removed (-:

Answer (score 3):

You can `fillna` by pass `dict`

```
df.fillna({'A':'Miss','B':"Your2",'C':df.C.median(),'D':df.D.mean()})
Out[373]: 
      A         B     C         D
0  A0A1   Railway  10.0  3.333333
1  A1A1  Shipping   3.0  1.000000
2  Miss  Shipping   3.0  2.000000
3  B1A1     Your2   1.0  7.000000
```

Comment: `df.fillna({'A':'Miss','B':"Your2",'C':df.C.median(),'D':df.D.median()})` ?

Comment: @jezrael yep you are right man , just give him more option here :-)

Comment: How to do that for group of similar variable, say I want to pass 'miss' for 20 variable then I need create dictionary for each variable. Ideally I have 1400 vars for that i need to do imputation.

Comment: @user9219405 keep your list of name using dict(zip(list1,list2))

Answer (score 2):

First replace [`median`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html) for numeric columns and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for non numeric:

```
df = df.fillna(df.median()).fillna('Missing')
print (df)

         A         B     C    D
0     A0A1   Railway  10.0  2.0
1     A1A1  Shipping   3.0  1.0
2  Missing  Shipping   3.0  2.0
3     B1A1   Missing   1.0  7.0
```